# Scanning for Network Printers On Cordova-Android

Tags: java, android, cordova-plugins

I am trying to build a plugin on cordova that can find the Bluetooth, USB and Network printer and print text, images, QR code, bar-codes... I have an issue in the network printer scanning, need some help with that. I have this code below that can search for the network printer connected to wifi. It works well with android 7 and 6 but in case of android 5, it is unable to return callback.This probably might be cause of the thread limit or something on android 5

```
 scanWifi(ips, new OnIPScanningCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanningComplete(List<String> results) {
                Log.d("TAG", "onScanningComplete: " + results.size()+" : "+results.toString());
                Printers printerList =null;
                for(String printerIps:results) {
                    String mac = getHardwareAddress(printerIps);
                    printerList = new Printers(printerIps, mac);
                    printers.put(printerIps);
                    list.add(printerList);
                }
                Log.d(TAGS,"The List of all wifi Printers : "+list);
            }
        });
        isStart = false;
    }

private static void scanWifi(final List<String> ips, final 
OnIPScanningCallback callback) {
    final Vector<String> results = new Vector<String>();
    final int totalSize = ips.size();
    final int splitSize = 10;
    final int[] index = {0};
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i += splitSize) {
        final List<String> child = new ArrayList<String>(ips.subList(i, Math.min(totalSize, i + splitSize)));

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (String ip : child) {
                    Log.d("TAG", " scanning : " + index[0] + ", ip: " + ip);
                    boolean isPrinter = connect(ip);
                    if (isPrinter) {
                        results.add(ip);
                    }
                    if (index[0] == ips.size() - 1) {
                        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Log.d("TAG", "scanning time: " + (end - start) / 1000);
                        callback.onScanningComplete(results);
                    } else {
                        index[0]++;
                    }
                }

            }
        }.start();
    }
}
  public interface OnIPScanningCallback {
    void onScanningComplete(List<String> results);
  }
```

I have also tried the async task and it works on all the versions of android but the problem is the process takes 170 to 193 secs which is way too long as in the above code it was able to do the same in 20 secs

```
 scanWifi(ips, new PrintingPlugin.OnIPScanningCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanningComplete(List<String> results) {
                Log.d(TAGS, "onScanningComplete: " + results.size() + " : " + results.toString());
                Printers printerList;
                for (String printerIps : results) {
                    String mac = getHardwareAddress(printerIps);
                    printerList = new Printers(printerIps, mac);
                    printers.put(printerIps);
                    list.add(printerList);
                }
                Log.d(TAGS, "The List of all wifi Printers : " + list);

            }
        });
        isStart = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAGS, "Error while scanning for wifi"+e.getMessage());
    }
    return printers;
}

private  Integer index = 0;

void resetIndex() {
    index = 0;
}

private  void scanWifi(final List<String> ips, final PrintingPlugin.OnIPScanningCallback callback) {
    Log.d(TAGS, " scanWifi" );
    final Vector<String> results = new Vector<String>();
    final int totalSize = ips.size();
    final int splitSize = 10;
    resetIndex();
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i += splitSize) {
        final List<String> child = new ArrayList<String>(ips.subList(i, Math.min(totalSize, i + splitSize)));
        executeTask(new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                synchronized (index) {
                    for (String ip : child) {
                        Log.d(TAGS, " scanning : " + index + ", ip: " + ip);
                        boolean isPrinter = connect(ip);
                        if (isPrinter) {
                            results.add(ip);
                        }
                        if (index == ips.size() - 1) {
                            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            Log.d(TAGS, "scanning time: " + (end - start) / 1000);
                            callback.onScanningComplete(results);
                        } else {
                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }

        });
    }

   public void executeTask(AsyncTask asyncTask) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    } else {
        asyncTask.execute();
    }
}
```

This is the message that I get when I run on android 5.

```
D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524290
```

Any help to make this thing work in any way (the first code to work on android 5 or the second code to work faster and in an efficient way ) will be deeply appreciated. I have looked on the issues related to this but I don't want to use print services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the index value was the reason why the callback was not sent, so to solve it just sending the callback as soon as you discover the Network Printer and storing it in a var(JSONArray in my case ) will give you the list of the printers and its effective.